# Creating a variable in R based on if another variable

Tags: r, date, if-statement, conditional-statements

In practical terms, I have a Tableau dashboard that I use to share student survey data with course instructors. I only share the data once an instructor has at least 10 responses. They do not get to see additional data beyond 10 responses until yet another 10 responses has been collected. This is for confidentiality purposes.

I am working on a data pipeline in R and would like to program the above logic as a single variable called "ReleasedtoDashboard" that gives "Yes" when an instructor has enough to be released and "No" when not. I do not know where to start and would greatly appreciate some help!

Dependent Variables:
SurveyEndDate - Date variable; this variables contains info on when the student completed the survey
CourseName: - String variable; this variable contains course names

More specifically, I need to create a calculated variable in R called "ReleasedToDashboard" that gives "Yes" when there are 10 of the same "CourseName" string value chronologically based on "SurveyEndDate". After the first ten (or before at least 10 is reached) of the same course is reached, "ReleasedToDashboard" should be "No" unless a multiple of 10 has been reached (e.g., 20) in which it should be "Yes". This pattern should repeat for all multiples of 10.

[example resulting ReleasedToDashboard variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0utv.png)

Please let me know if you have any questions. This is my first time posting on here and it has been a while since I used R. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I tried using the following code but it only succeeded in assigning "Yes" to every multiple 10 of a specific "Course Name" value sorted by "SurveyEndDate." I need "Yes" to also be assigned to "ReleasedToDashboard" for all observations that are not a multiple of ten as long as the nearest upward multiple of ten (say we are looking at an observation, a point in time based on SurveyEndDate, where 4 observations/survey responses have been completed, then "ReleasedToDashboard" should get assigned "Yes" as long as there are at least 10 observations/responses for that "CourseName", same thing for say 16 and 20, or 31 and 40.) has been meant in terms of the count of "CourseName" of a particular value.

```
   `library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    DF <- DF %>%
  arrange(CourseName, SurveyEndDate) %>%
  group_by(CourseName) %>%
  mutate(
    count = row_number(),
    nearest_mult_10 = ceiling(count / 10) * 10,
    ReleasedToDashboard = ifelse(nearest_mult_10 <= count, "Yes", "No")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-count, -nearest_mult_10)`


structure(list(ReleasedToDashboard = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "No"), CourseName = c("Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", 
"Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", 
"Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", 
"Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", "Anatomy", 
"Biology", "Biology", "Biology", "Biology", "Biology", "Chemistry", 
"Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Chemistry", 
"Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Chemistry", "Chemistry", 
"Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Psychology", "Psychology", 
"Psychology", "Psychology", "Psychology", "Psychology", "Psychology", 
"Psychology", "Psychology", "Psychology", "Psychology", "Psychology", 
"Psychology"), SurveyEndDate = structure(c(1705449600, 1705536000, 
1705622400, 1705708800, 1706659200, 1706745600, 1706832000, 1707955200, 
1708041600, 1708128000, 1708214400, 1708300800, 1708387200, 1708473600, 
1708560000, 1708646400, 1708732800, 1708819200, 1708905600, 1708992000, 
1709078400, 1706054400, 1706140800, 1706227200, 1706313600, 1706400000, 
1705795200, 1705881600, 1706140800, 1706227200, 1706572800, 1706918400, 
1707004800, 1707264000, 1707350400, 1707436800, 1707523200, 1705363200, 
1705968000, 1706054400, 1705017600, 1705104000, 1705190400, 1705276800, 
1706313600, 1706400000, 1706486400, 1707091200, 1707177600, 1707609600, 
1707696000, 1707782400, 1707868800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-53L))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Matthew wroblewski! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: It will be much easier for people to help if you can share your data as code instead of a picture. e.g. you run `dput(YOUR_DATA)` or `dput(head(YOUR_DATA, 50))` if 50 rows is a good amount of data, and paste the output into the body of your question.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: I added the dataset as code. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: I updated my post some attempted code. It doesn't quite get there but perhaps it will help to illustrate what I am trying to do. Please let me know if anyone has any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got there with the code below! It is not best practice, but I added the replace.na clean up action at the bottom because I believe 'tenth_acr_yes[nearest_mult_10]=="Yes" ' spits out "NA" when there is not a "Yes" to reference, i.e., it's basically trying to index a value that does not exist. Not sure how to program that away so I just set NA = "No". I am open to improvements if anyone has one! Thank you!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

acrs.survey.except.med <- acrs.survey.except.med %>%
  arrange(acr, EndDate) %>%
  group_by(acr) %>%
  mutate(
    count = row_number(),
    nearest_mult_10 = ceiling(count / 10) * 10,
    tenth_acr_yes = ifelse(nearest_mult_10 <= count, "Yes", "No"),
    ReleasedToDashboard = ifelse(tenth_acr_yes[nearest_mult_10]=="Yes" & count <= nearest_mult_10, "Yes", "No")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-tenth_acr_yes, -count, -nearest_mult_10)

acrs.survey.except.med$ReleasedToDashboard <- replace_na(acrs.survey.except.med$ReleasedToDashboard, "No")
```

Comment: P.s. acr = coursename